# Why Java XPath.evaluate() throws NullPointerException when using an entity?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, dtd

I have problem with parsing xml file, using XPath. My file looks like:

```
<root>
   <node1>nodeText</node1>
   <node2>node2Text</node2>
   &general-copyrights-short;
</root>
```

And java code:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(selector, inputDocument,
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

When I run it, I get:

```
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But when I delete last part of xml: `&general-copyrights-short;`, or copy it into child elements (node1, node2) everything works just fine. What can I do?

Comment: Where is defined the entity `general-copyrights-short`?

Comment: best is to stick to valid xml. the &general-copyright-short; part isn't recognized as such

Comment: It is not real xml. In real one, there is dtd reference with entities, sorry. When I've placed &general-copyrights-short; inside child element, everything is fine.

Comment: Please show us the stack trace for the NullPointerException. It looks like a bug to me. Are you using the default XPath engine in the JDK, or some other implementation? My suspicion is that the XPath engine doesn't correctly handle an entity reference node in the DOM.

Comment: Stack trace: https://pastebin.com/vaAPwUai

Comment: Does the NullPointerException also occur when you replace the DTD entity with regular text?

Comment: No, it works fine.

Comment: That narrows the scope.

Comment: Show the xpath you are using "selector" and also post the stack trace of XPathExpressionException.

Comment: My selector: //* . And stack trace: https://pastebin.com/vaAPwUai

Comment: It looks like a bug in xalan library. I will write workaround for this situation. Thanks for Your help! :)